# pandas merge multi row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This may be a really easy question but I am having a hard time to figure out.

I have two python data frames that I am trying to join, here is a snip of the information on each

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj9qe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QboLA.png)

What I am trying to accomplish is to add the name showing in the first dataframe to each row in the second, however when I try to do a pandas.merge its only doing one row

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that df_1 is that in which you have columns named *name* and *networkId*, and df_2 is the dataframe to which you want to attach the *name* information via the key *id*.

Then,

```
merged = df_2.merge(df_1[["networkId","name"]], left_on="id", right_on="networkId", how="left")
print(merged.head())
```

If this is not in line with your example, please provide some initial data.